# SSE send the new data only

Tags: html, server-sent-events, server

is there a way to make server send only the new data if occurred no to send the same data every n seconds although there is no change in the data?

Thank you

Comment: You are in control of the data sent.  If you want to only send the new data, only send the new data.

Comment: excuse me i expressed my question in wrong way, i mean send the data if new not the new data,for example i have a table in mysql database this table has changes in its row beside adding new rows, i send some rows according to a query which may contains updated rows and new ones, the server script which is jsp file get the query from the database, is there is a way to know if the server (tomcat) sent this same data before or not? if yes not send if no send?